# Is it possible to create a column with two types?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, column, choice-field, single-line-of-text

Is there any possibility in sharepoint to create single column which will have both single line of text and choice as column type?

Please suggest if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you enable 'Fill-in' option in the column settings. You can define options for choice field and user is also able to "select" own value by typing it.

[image]

Comment: If the input for single line and the drop down are two different things (which the input of single line shall not show the drop down selection), would it still possible to make it in one column? or it can do any code edit in SharePoint Designer

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**.

You can create a new column with type as **Choice** and choose **Allow 'Fill-in' choices** option to **Yes** in column settings.

This column will allow you to add the below things:

1. Select any choice from the Dropdown(Choice given in column settings).
2. Input Single Line of Text. This text will not be available under the choices dropdown but, still you can enter any free text in it.